# Is it possible to reuse annotations from one model in another one in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm using Django 2.2.16 and I was trying to get rid of replicated logic across querysets. I didn't manage to find a way (without impacting performance, like subquery in `select` clause) to reuse annotations from one model in annotations of another one.

Here is my current implementation:

```py
# models.py

from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from querysets import PostManager, TagManager

class Tag(models.Model):
    objects = TagManager()

    name = CICharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()

    STATUS_ACCEPTED = "ACCEPTED"
    STATUS_DECLINED = "DECLINED"
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACCEPTED, "Accepted"),
        (STATUS_DECLINED, "Declined"),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        default=STATUS_DECLINED,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        max_length=63,
        verbose_name="Źródło ogłoszenia",
    )
    expiration_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags =   models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, db_index=True)


# querysets.py
from django.db.models import Case, Count, Q, QuerySet, When, Manager


class PostQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def annotate_statuses(self):
        today = date.today()

        return self.annotate(
            live=Case(
                When(
                    Q(status="ACCEPTED")
                    & (Q(expiration_date__isnull=True) | Q(expiration_date__gte=today)),
                    then=True,
                ),
                default=False,
                output_field=models.BooleanField(),
            ),
            expired=Case(
                When(
                    Q(status="ACCEPTED")
                    & (Q(expiration_date__isnull=False) & Q(expiration_date__lt=today)),
                    then=True,
                ),
                default=False,
                output_field=models.BooleanField(),
            ),
        )

PostManager = Manager.from_queryset(PostQuerySet)

class TagQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def annotate_live_listings():
        today = date.today()

        return queryset.annotate(
            posts_count=Count("post"),
            listings_count=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(
                        Q(post__status="ACCEPTED")
                        & (Q(post__expiration_date__isnull=True) | Q(post__expiration_date__gte=today)),
                        then=1,
                    ),
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                    default=0,
                )
            ),
        )

TagManager = Manager.from_queryset(TagQuerySet)
```

My question is if it's possible to reimplement method `annotate_live_listings` in `TagQuerySet` to reuse somehow already implemented `annotate_statuses` from `PostQuerySet`. Currently, because of the code being more or less copied over, I've got logic of `live` annotation in two places.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Mixin is great for reusing methods like this.  It is possible to re-use model field definitions as well.   https://riptutorial.com/django/example/16496/model-mixins

Comment: Thanks Michael, but your suggestion would work only if those classes had the same `live` annotation. As you can see `Tag` annotations in method `annotate_live_listings` produce annotation called `listings_count`, it's based on different fields and is calculated as a count of previously mentioned `live` listings. I'm looking more for a way to reference `Listing` annotation from `Tag` annotation.